# Cannot reposition axes in bar graph OxyPlot xamarin

Tags: android, graph, xamarin.android, oxyplot

I have displayed a bar graph in android xamarin. I want to display a simple bar graph with 3 categories.

What I want:-

[image]

What I get :-

[image]

So currently my graph is showing horizontally. I want it to show as in figure 1.

Here is my code:-

```
var plotModel1 = new PlotModel();
            plotModel1.LegendOrientation = LegendOrientation.Vertical;
            plotModel1.PlotAreaBorderColor = OxyColors.White;




            var barSeries1 = new BarSeries();

            for (int i = 0; i < barValues.Length && i < colorPallete.Length && i<barTitles.Length; i++)
            {
                barSeries1.Items.Add(new BarItem(barValues[i], -1) { Color = OxyColor.Parse(colorPallete[i]) });
}

 plotModel1.Series.Add(barSeries1);
MyModel = plotModel1;
  barPlotView.Model = MyModel;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of BarSeries you should look up ColumnSeries. It will give you the horizontal graph you are looking for.